# How to get non-rigged keyframe animations using assimp and collada?

Tags: opengl, collada, assimp

How do I extract keyframe animations(without bones) from .dae(collada) files using assimp? I followed tutorials on how to achieve this for skeletal animations. But I need to be able to do this for animations that are not rigged and that rely on keyframes instead.

I know how to get the animation and mesh data from .dae files using assimp but how would I use this to animate keyframes and interpolate between them? All tutorials I found only show how to do this with bones. How would assimp represent animations if no bones exist?

[Edit] code for bones

```
void SkeletalAnimation::Animate(float pDeltaTime, Bone& pSkeleton, Pose& pPose, glm::mat4& pParentTransform) {
        Animation& _currentAnimation = mAnimationMap[*mCurrentAnimation];
        
        BoneTransforms& _boneTransforms = _currentAnimation.boneTransforms[pSkeleton.name];
        pDeltaTime = fmod(pDeltaTime, _currentAnimation.duration);
        
        //Calculate translations
        GetSegment(&mCurrentSegment, _boneTransforms.translationTimestamps, pDeltaTime);

        glm::vec3 _translation = glm::mix(
            _boneTransforms.translations[mCurrentSegment.segment - 1], 
            _boneTransforms.translations[mCurrentSegment.segment], 
            mCurrentSegment.fracture);

        //Calculate rotations
        GetSegment(&mCurrentSegment, _boneTransforms.rotationTimetamps, pDeltaTime);

        glm::quat _rotation = glm::slerp(
            _boneTransforms.rotations[mCurrentSegment.segment - 1], 
            _boneTransforms.rotations[mCurrentSegment.segment], 
            mCurrentSegment.fracture);

        //Calculate scalings
        GetSegment(&mCurrentSegment, _boneTransforms.scalingTimetamps, pDeltaTime);

        glm::vec3 _scaling = glm::mix(
            _boneTransforms.scalings[mCurrentSegment.segment - 1],
            _boneTransforms.scalings[mCurrentSegment.segment],
            mCurrentSegment.fracture);

        glm::mat4 _translationMatrix = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), _translation);
        glm::mat4 _rotationMatrix = glm::toMat4(_rotation);
        glm::mat4 _scalingMatrix = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0f), _scaling); glm::mat4(1.0f);
        
        glm::mat4 _localTransform = _translationMatrix * _rotationMatrix * _scalingMatrix;
        glm::mat4 _globalTransform = pParentTransform * _localTransform;

        pPose[pSkeleton.id] = mGlobalInverseTransform * _globalTransform * pSkeleton.offset;

        for (Bone& _child : pSkeleton.children) {
            Animate(pDeltaTime, _child, pPose, _globalTransform);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not all nodes are bones. In your code you should be checking whether a node is a bone or not. When an animation happens without bones, there are still ai_nodes with keyframes that need to be loaded. Then you can concatenate transforms to bring the model node to world space.

Comment: So I would do transforms on all nodes and not just the ones that are bones(since there would be no bones anyway)?

Comment: Assimp should have a node with the same name as your model. With bones you use the offset matrix to go into bone space and then you concatenate all the parent nodes until you get to the bone. final = global_inverse * parent_concatenated * current_node * offset . With no bones just do final = parent_concatenated * current_node making sure that you start from the root and end at the model node. I would add a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code in your question (in this case how you are transforming things with the bones).

Comment: I edited my question to show my code. So it seems like what you suggest is to instead of doing animaton on a per bone basis. I do it on a per node basis and without offsets.

Comment: Also how would I pass this onto shaders? with skeletal animation I pass in the all the bone with respective transforms appled. Would I be doing it with all the nodes now?